# $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2}\cong\frac{\mathbb{S}^{2}}{\sim}$

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently having some problems finding an explicit homeomorphism such that $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2}\cong\frac{\mathbb{S}^{2}}{\sim}$.

However, I'm aware at the same time that:

1) If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an identification, $\frac{X}{R_f}\cong Y$.

2) $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2=(\mathbb{R}^3-\{(0,0,0)\})/{\approx}$ where $x\approx y \iff \exists\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x=\lambda y$.

I have the feeling that it's almost trivial at this point, but I still don't know what to do.

Comment: Since $\approx$ is a binary relation symbol, normally a certain amount of space appears before and after it in expressions like $a\approx b$.  But in quotients $A/{\approx}$ the spacing is no longer appropriate, so writing A/{\approx}, with {curly braces}, eliminates it so that you see $A/{\approx}$ rather than $A/\approx{}$. I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Look at the map 
$$
\begin{align}
f: \Bbb{S}^2 &\to \Bbb{RP}^2 \\
(x, y, z) &\mapsto [x: y: z],
\end{align}
$$
where the latter are [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates).  Convince yourself that this is a $2$-to-$1$ quotient map with fibers given by pairs of antipodal points.  So it descends to a homeomorphism
$$
\begin{align}
f: \Bbb{S}^2/\sim &\to \Bbb{RP}^2 \\
\{\pm(x, y, z)\} &\mapsto [x: y: z].
\end{align}
$$